# Scrapy not running after integrating discord python

Tags: python, scrapy, discord

I made a script that scrapes diffrent locations for free PC games. I got it working good and wanted to integrate it into my discord channel. My problem is after adding the commands for discord it no longer scrapes. It’s like the discord is blocking the rest of the script from running. So what I would like to do is separate these 2 out and have it call the scrape function when I do a #update or whatever in discord. What would be the best way of doing this? To run the scraping bot I just use “scrapy crawl botname”. Could I just use the os.system(“scrapy crawl bitname”) or is there a better way? I will update this with samples of my code An fix formatting when I get to my desk. Thanks for Any suggestions!

Here is my pipelines.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import pymongo
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import chalk
import csv
from more_itertools import unique_everseen
with open("reddit.csv",'r') as f, open("redditu.csv",'w') as out_file:
out_file.writelines(unique_everseen(f))


class DuplicatesPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.titles_seen = set()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if item['title'] in self.titles_seen:
        raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
    else:
        self.titles_seen.add(item['title'])
        return item


class MongoDBPipeline(object):
def __init__(self):

    uri = "HIDDEN"
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
    db = client["freegames"]
    self.collection = db['post']


def process_item(self, item, spider):
    valid = True
    for data in item:
        if not data:
            valid = False
            raise DropItem("Missing {0}!".format(data))
    if valid:
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
        log.msg("Added to MongoDB database!",
                level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider)
    return item
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='#')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():

print ("Scrappy Bot loaded!")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def free(ctx):
os.system('python redditbot.py')

f = open('redditu.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    #print(row)
    await bot.say('Free Games: {}'.format(row))




@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def info(ctx, user: discord.Member):
await bot.say("The users name is: {}".format(user.name))
await bot.say("The users ID is: {}".format(user.id))
await bot.say("The users status is: {}".format(user.status))
await bot.say("The users highest role is: {}".format(user.top_role))
await bot.say("The user joined at: {}".format(user.joined_at)) 

bot.run("HIDDEN")
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'redditfreegames'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['redditfreegames.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'redditfreegames.spiders'

#Export as CSV Feed
FEED_FORMAT = "csv"
FEED_URI = "reddit.csv"

#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2

ITEM_PIPELINES = {'redditfreegames.pipelines.DuplicatesPipeline':300, 
'redditfreegames.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline':800, }
```

and my actual crawling script

```
class RedditbotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'redditbot'
    allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/FreeGamesOnSteam/']

    def parse(self, response):
        #Extracting the content using css selectors
        titles = response.css('.title.may-blank::text').extract()
        links = response.css(".title::attr(href)").extract()

        #Give the extracted content row wise
        for item in zip(titles,links):
            #create a dictionary to store the scraped info
            scraped_info = {
                'title' : item[0],
                'links' : item[1]

            }

            #yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
            yield scraped_info
```

I have alot of code in there im not even using, such as the saving to mongodb as im currently just saving to a csv and pulling from that. Will go through and clean it up.

Comment: Please be clear and post everything together including your code snippet. Your question is too clear to answer.

Comment: updated to include some code, very new to python so trying to learn as I go here so please ignore the terrible coding practices. Thanks